# binary search keeps returning element not present //

Tags: java, binary-search

I tried to create the algorithm as practice, but I'm not too sure as for where I blundered but I keep getting "Element not present" even if the array is sorted.//

---

I'm trying to create random arrays and sort it at the same time. Meanwhile, I want to see how many comparisons it takes, and also measure how much time it takes for this program to run in (ms).

Some problems at the moment:

Keeps printing: Element not present, and time as 0. I know binary is time efficient, but I'm kind of sketchy with this being at 0/ or at 1 to 2 in many cases when the x is at 5000 or a million to 20 million. I think that should take some time still.

```js
//main

import java.util.Arrays;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author temur
 */
public class main {
    public static int[] randomIntArray(int n, int low, int high) {
        // Set up for generating random numbers
        int range = high - low + 1;
        int shift = low;

        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * range) + shift;
        }

        return arr;
    }

    public static boolean isSorted(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void print(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
//____________________________________________________________

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        binary ob = new binary();
        int[] arr = randomIntArray(1, 20000000, 20000000);

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int x = 55432;
        int n = 1;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int result = ob.binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x);

        System.out.println(
                "Element in evaluation: " + x);
        if (result
                == -1) {
            System.out.println("Element not present");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Element found at index: "
                    + result);
        }
         System.out.println(
                "Ammount of comparisons: " + ob.count);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time (ms):"+ (endTime - startTime));
    }
}
```

```js
//binary

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author temur
 */
public class binary {
    
    int count = 0;

    int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
        
        count += 1;
        if (r >= l) {
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
            if (arr[mid] == x) {
                return mid;
            }
            if (arr[mid] > x) {
                return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x);
            }
            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an array 1 element long, with elements randomly generated between 20000000 and 20000000. In other words, it's always `{20000000}`. Of course 55432 isn't going to be in that array, and the binary search is going to figure that out pretty fast.

Comment: I just wanted it where it keeps looking for the value/ whether it be if it does the search again

sorry for the confusion

https://jsfiddle.net/rxymwpbq/

Answer (score 0):

It is simple that your randomIntArray  with values you pass is going to give single length array.

**Run Code**:

```
int[] arr = randomIntArray(1, 20000000, 20000000);
  System.out.println("Array "+Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**Output**:

> Array [20000000]

so the value **55432** is not present in this array and that is a very fast to figure it out.

Comment: if I do 

           int[] arr = randomIntArray(1, 1000000, 20000000);

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int x = 1100000;

it still give's me no element in evaluation

Comment: @hellothere: You are now generating *one* random number between 1000000 and 20000000. Why would that random number happen to be 1100000?